# Remove near black borders on Landsat 8 overview images

Tags: gdal, digital-image-processing, landsat-8, image-mosaic, image-pyramids

I want to eliminate near black pixels around edges of Landsat-8 overview. I'm interested in doing it not for the entire image but some extent, so I clipped it. I tried using GDAL nearblack utility, but faced the problem that it doesn't take into account image border pixels.

Calling

```
nearblack -of GTiff -nb 1 -o mask.tif input.tif
```

Produces following result:

[image: nearblack -of GTiff -nb 1 -o mask.tif input.tif]
When I expected that the output would have looked like this:
[image: desired output]

Is there a way to force GDAL nearblack utility to ignore pixels around image borders?
To achieve my goal I also tried applying erosion with different structuring elements, but erosion produces "torn edges".